# Use listing with automatic page break

Tags: listings

I want to put some of my python-code in the appendix of my latex file. For that I use the following code:

```
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.95\textwidth}
\lstinputlisting[caption=Python script used for fitting multiple ochi-hubble-functions to the measured data, language=Python]{../Bolge/fit_best.py}
\label{pyFit}
\end{minipage}
```

The problem I have here is that my code is bigger than one page, but it does not make a page break when ending the page. (I am using minipage here for a proper line break in the code).
How can I improve the code so that my `lstlisting` will make a new page if necessary?

Comment: Don't use minipage. listings has its own keys to change the width.

Comment: BTW, package `listings` provides option `label` for a label, which can be referenced by `\ref`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Do you want to write up an answer?

Comment: @TeXnician well imho the question has been abandoned, but I added an answer ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use minipage. listings has its own keys to change the width e.g. `linewidth`, `xleftmargin` and more. See "5.8 Margins and line shape" in the documentation of listings.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings,lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\lstinputlisting[xrightmargin=0.05\linewidth,breaklines,breakatwhitespace,caption=inputenc]{inputenc.sty}

\end{document}
```

[image]